# how to change state from sent to read when click item

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-mobile

I need to update state of sales when I click in item list view but i can't

this is my code

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int 
 position, long id) {
  ODataRow row = OCursorUtils.toDatarow((Cursor)mAdapter.getItem(position));


OValues values =new OValues();
);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hello try to call that 'mark_as_read' directly.
Example is I am calling that action_confirm method from 'sale.order' model

`odoo.callMethod("sale.order",//model name
                 "action_confirm",//method name
                  new OArguments() {{add(id);}},//id if particular record
                   null);`